# Generating Integers and Discarding the Lowest

Tags: java, random

I'm writing a program that is supposed to generate four random integers (from 1 to 6), then discard the lowest value and add the remaining three together. I created four variables with

```
int var1 = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
int var2 = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
int var3 = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
int var4 = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
```

How would I get the program to detect the smallest variable? (or the variable tied for smallest) I think I may have a method, but it would be very long and tedious to write and I'm sure there's a simpler way that I'm just not realizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother detecting until after the add.

```
return var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 - min(var1, min(var2, min(var3, var4)));
```

Comment: Thanks, i wouldn't have thought of expressing it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Put the ints in an array. Create an int that represents the smallest number, set that to the first value in the array. Then loop through the array to look for any smaller values.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd likely go with Kleric's answer, but if you want there's an option that's possibly a bit more readable; add the numbers to a `List`, then use `Collections.sort(list)` to sort them in ascending order, then simply sum from index 1:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ints.add(rand.nextInt(6) + 1);
}
Collections.sort(ints);
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < ints.size(); i++) {
    sum += ints.get(i);
}
```

This is obviously a somewhat unnecessary sort, and as such isn't the best performing way of achieving this, but I do believe it's readable and maintainable enough to be worth a mention in case this isn't performance critical code.